# Replace image path to base64 string with several containing string

Tags: c#, string, uwp, tobase64string

I have a string containing "https://tryout.pendukasi.id/upload/" and I want to replace every string that contains "https://tryout.pendukasi.id/upload/" to "data:image/jpeg; base64".

Code:

```
foreach (StorageFile file in files)
{
    string soalP = file.Path;
    if (question.Pertanyaan.ToString().Contains("https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/"))
    {
        byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(soalP);
            string base64ImageRepresentation = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
            soal = Regex.Replace(question.Pertanyaan.ToString(), "\"https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/" + file.Name + "\"", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64ImageRepresentation);
    }
}
```

I am having a problem, if the string contains one "https://tryout.pendukasi.id/upload/", then the string is successfully replaced, but if it contains several "https://tryout.pendukasi.id/upload/", for example : `"<p>Perhatikan ayat-ayat Surat al-Falaq berikut ini!<br /><img src=\"https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/3-1.JPG\" /><br /><img src=\"https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/3-2.JPG\" /><br /><img src=\"https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/3-3.JPG\" /><br /><img src=\"https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/3-4.JPG\" /><br /><img src=\"https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/3-5.JPG\" /><br />Urutan ayat dalam Surat al-Falaq yang benar adalah &hellip;.</p>"`, then the string was not successfully changed. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you're replacing file by file, and it's previous change keeps being changed by:

```
soal = Regex.Replace(question.Pertanyaan.ToString(), "\"https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/" + file.Name + "\"", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64ImageRepresentation);
```

An approach would be be saving your regex replaced string to a variable.
By doing so, your replacements wouldn't be overwritten:

```
string soal = question.Pertanyaan.ToString();

foreach (StorageFile file in files)
{
    string soalP = file.Path;
    if (soal.Contains("https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/"))
    {
        byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(soalP);
            string base64ImageRepresentation = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
            soal = Regex.Replace(soal, "\"https://tryout.pendidikan.id/upload/" + file.Name + "\"", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64ImageRepresentation);
    }
}
```